# Mysql 8 takes 2 minutes to sort an empty dataset

Tags: sql, mysql, performance, query-optimization

Mysql 8 takes 2 minutes to sort an empty set

The following table on 8.0.33 MySQL Community Server

```
CREATE TABLE `eventiAcc` (
  `chiave` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tipo` tinyint NOT NULL,
  `account` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `utente` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestp` datetime NOT NULL,
  `dato` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `extra` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`chiave`),
  KEY `idx1` (`account`,`tipo`,`timestp`),
  KEY `idx2` (`tipo`,`utente`),
  KEY `idx_timestp` (`timestp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=40908800 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3
```

The table contains 20 million records.

if I run this query

```
 SELECT chiave, tipo, account, utente, timestp, dato, extra 
FROM eventiAcc 
WHERE utente=25169 
AND tipo=26 
AND dato='aggIndFatt';
```

the resulti is
`Empty set (0.06 sec)`
because the where clause is optimized on index  KEY `idx2` (`tipo`,`utente`)

but if I run

```
 SELECT chiave, tipo, account, utente, timestp, dato, extra 
FROM eventiAcc 
WHERE utente=25169 
AND tipo=26 
AND dato='aggIndFatt' 
ORDER BY timestp DESC LIMIT 1;
```

the resulti is
Empty set (**2 min 8.12 sec**)

I suspect that mysql server sorts the entire table before applying the where clause trying to optimize the SORT on index KEY `idx_timestp` (`timestp`) before applying where clause.

Other tests that seems to support my assumption:

```
SELECT chiave, tipo, account, utente, timestp, dato, extra FROM eventiAcc WHERE utente=25169 AND tipo=26;
+----------+------+---------+--------+---------------------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| chiave   | tipo | account | utente | timestp             | dato         | extra                                                                                         |
+----------+------+---------+--------+---------------------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 12703973 |   26 |    4445 |  25169 | 2020-08-14 20:58:42 | aggCaratt    | Generali     

….

| 40908354 |   26 |    4445 |  25169 | 2024-01-29 11:39:10 | selectUser   | oldUser=null                                                                                  |
+----------+------+---------+--------+---------------------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
4826 rows in set (0.08 sec)
```

```
select chiave, tipo, account, utente, timestp, dato, extra FROM eventiAcc WHERE utente=25169 AND tipo=26 ORDER BY timestp DESC LIMIT 1 ;
+----------+------+---------+--------+---------------------+------------+--------------+
| chiave   | tipo | account | utente | timestp             | dato       | extra        |
+----------+------+---------+--------+---------------------+------------+--------------+
| 40908354 |   26 |    4445 |  25169 | 2024-01-29 11:39:10 | selectUser | oldUser=null |
+----------+------+---------+--------+---------------------+------------+--------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

The strangest behavior is that if the I drop "KEY `idx_timestp` (`timestp`)" index and I lunch the same query that takes 2 minutes

```
 SELECT chiave, tipo, account, utente, timestp, dato, extra 
FROM eventiAcc 
WHERE utente=25169 
AND tipo=26 
AND dato='aggIndFatt' 
ORDER BY timestp DESC LIMIT 1
```

he result is

`Empty set (0.08 sec)`

Dropping the KEY `idx_timestp` (`timestp`) index solves the problem but the index is needed in many different queroes on that table

It is any way to suggest Mysql 8 to ignore the index on timestp field?
Which is the best approach to solve this performance issue?

Comment: Please add the following the following indexes and try again , please show explain plan. `alter table eventiAcc add index ut_tp_dt_times(utente,tipo,dato,timestp) ;`  
`alter table eventiAcc add index ut_tp_dt_times(tipo,utente,dato,timestp) ;`

Comment: This is for SQL Server, so just a comment, but in the SQL Server world the database keeps statistics, which it uses to make estimates, which the engine will use to decide whether it's likely to be more efficient to filter and then sort or sort and then filter. This kind of bad query plan happens when the statistics get out of date. It also caches query plans, where changing the input to a cached plan can result in suboptimal execution, and this can be fixed by including a hint telling the DB to NOT cache the plan. But again: SQL Server. I do not know how MySQL handles this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySql allows to ignore a specific index by adding `IGNORE INDEX (index_name)` after the table name.

So in your case the query should become:

```
SELECT chiave, tipo, account, utente, timestp, dato, extra 
FROM eventiAcc 
IGNORE INDEX (idx_timestp) 
WHERE utente=25169 
AND tipo=26 
AND dato='aggIndFatt' 
ORDER BY timestp DESC LIMIT 1
```

Just for reference, the following keywords also exist: `USE INDEX` and `FORCE INDEX` that allow respectively to suggest an index to the optimizer and force the optimizer to use a specific index.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that "sorting" the "empty set" is the problem, but rather the time it takes to discover that the set is empty.

A secondary index works in one of two ways:

- "Using index" (see output from `EXPLAIN SELECT`) -- This means the index was "covering".  Discovering that there are zero rows is done entirely in the index's BTree makes the query fast.
- Not covering.  Your first, slow, query could use only one column (`tipo`); it had to reach over into the data BTree to check the other two columns.  This back-and-forth was quite costly in your case.

The solution is to add another index with the 3 columns tested in `WHERE` clause

Your second query would benefit from

```
INDEX(utente, tipo, data,    -- in any order (since all tests are "=")
      timestp)               -- last
```

This will be "covering" for both queries and make the sort go away.  And it will probably avoid any need for "index hints"

MySQL will almost never use two indexes in a single `SELECT`.

Comment: *-- in any order (since all tests are "=")* as far as I know integers are tested first please correct me If I'm wrong

Comment: @ErgestBasha - virtually any datatype.  `WHERE myint=123 AND mystr='abc'` is happy to use `INDEX(mystr, myint)` (either order).  `TEXT` cannot be indexed, but `VARCHAR` can.  `SET` does not make sense; `ENUM` is ambiguous (will it order by the string or the internal TINY INT?)   Date types are stored as numeric things that work well with `=` and `<` (etc).  `FLOAT` is unlikely to work as expected because of rounding.  `VARCHAR` has the complexity of `COLLATIONs` which allow for case folding ('r'='R', etc) and accent stripping.